# MySQL - Selecting the items that have the highest count of trips but not repeated

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I am trying to make a system where it finds a list of stops (stop_code) that has the most trips.

**Like:**

```
SELECT count(`trip_id`) as `count` FROM `stop_times` 
WHERE `time` BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:05:00' 
GROUP BY `stop_code` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

But since, I am pulling results

```
stop code: 3000 count: 9    
stop code: 3011 count: 7    
stop code: 3030 count: 3
```

**In those counts lets say, it includes:**

```
stop code: 3000 list: trip1,trip2,trip3,trip4,trip5,trip6,trip7,trip8,trip9
stop code: 3011 list: trip3,trip4,trip5,trip6,trip7,trip10,trip11
stop code: 3030 list: trip2,trip3,trip4,trip12
```

How can I adjust that query to make it let's say:

```
stop code: 3000 list: trip1,trip2,trip3,trip4,trip5,trip6,trip7,trip8,trip9
stop code: 3011 list: trip10,trip11
stop code: 3030 list: trip12
```

As in a unique set of `trip_id`.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the formating, i was just adjusting it

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want duplicates between the different stop codes, why is `trip4` in both `3000` and `3030`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. edit to: stop code: 3030 list: trip12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that gets the lowest `stop_code` for each `trip_id`, before doing the counts.

```
SELECT stop_code, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT trip_id, MIN(stop_code) AS stop_code
      FROM stop_times
      WHERE `time` BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:05:00' 
      GROUP BY trip_id) AS x
GROUP BY stop_code
ORDER BY count DESC
```